# HP pavillon X360 battry charging is not worling

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

I removed Windows 10 and installed Ubuntu 16.04.

The battery is no longer charging.

When I unplug the power cable, my PC immediately turns off.

the command:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 22
```

gives:

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.1 present.

Handle 0x002D, DMI type 22, 26 bytes
Portable Battery
    Location: Primary
    Manufacturer: <BAD INDEX>
    Manufacture Date: <BAD INDEX>
    Serial Number: <BAD INDEX>
    Name: <BAD INDEX>
    Design Capacity: Unknown
    Design Voltage: Unknown
    SBDS Version: <BAD INDEX>
    Maximum Error: 0%
    SBDS Chemistry: <BAD INDEX>
    OEM-specific Information: 0x000A070C
```

and the command

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

gives:

```
  native-path:          (null)
  power supply:         no
  updated:              jeu. 01 janv. 1970 01:00:00 CET (1604511715 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  unknown
    warning-level:       unknown
    icon-name:          '(null)'
```

Does anyone know how I can get the battery to charge again?

Comment: This is probably not software related, but a hardware problem.  To rule this out, you can test if your battery charges in a live session (the "Try Ubuntu" option from installation media).  If your battery still doesn't charge in the live session, your battery is probably dead and needs to be replaced.

Comment: It is a new PC and the battery was working withj windows. but when i installed ubuntu it stops charging.

Comment: So what happened when you tried the live session?

Comment: does it charge when powered off and plugged in.